# Redux - How to calculate the cost of a list of carts from a normalised state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

am fairly new to React/Redux. I have a normalised redux state that looks like so:

```
users: {
  user1: {
    id: 'user1',
    name: 'Jim',
    carts: ['cart1', 'cart2']
  }
},
carts: {
  cart1: {
    id: 'cart1',
    items: ['item1', 'item2']
  },
  cart2: {
    id: 'cart2',
    items: ['item3', 'item4']
  }
},
items: {
  item1: {
    id: 'item1',
    price: 1
  },
  item2: {
    id: 'item2',
    price: 2
  },
  item3: {
    id: 'item3',
    price: 3
  },
  item4: {
    id: 'item4',
    price: 4
  }
}
```

I have also created the following selectors:

item.selector.js:

```
export const selectAllItems = state => state.items

export const selectItems = itemIds => createSelector(
  [selectAllItems],
  items => Object.keys(items)
    .filter(itemId => itemIds.includes(itemId))
    .reduce((arr, itemId) => {
      arr.push(items[itemId])
      return arr
    }, [])
)

export const totalItemsCost = itemIds => createSelector(
  [selectAllItems],
  items => Object.keys(items)
    .filter(itemId => itemIds.includes(itemId))
    .reduce((cost, itemId) => {
      cost += blocs[itemId].price
      return cost
    }, 0)
)
```

cart.selector.js:

```
export const selectAllCarts = state => state.carts

export const selectCart = cartId => createSelector(
  [selectAllCarts],
  carts => carts[cartId]
)

export const selectCarts = cartIds => createSelector(
  [selectAllCarts],
  options => Object.keys(carts)
    .filter(key => cartIds.includes(key))
    .reduce((arr, key) => {
      arr.push(options[key])
      return arr
    }, [])
)
```

user.selector.js:

```
export const selectUsers = state => state.users

export const selectUser = userId => createSelector(
  [selectUsers],
  users => users[userId]
)
```

I wish to display the total cost of each cart on the user page and have the following React component:

```
class User extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      {  this.props.carts.map(cart => (<DisplayComponent id={ cart.id } cost={ $TOTAL_CART_COST }/>))}
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  user: selectUser(ownProps.match.params.userId)(state),
  carts: selectCarts(selectUser(ownProps.match.params.userId)(state).carts)(state)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(User)
```

Im unsure on the best way to achieve this. I have tried creating a cartCost field which is updated by the reducer, like this:

```
case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.payload.cartId]: {
      ...state[action.payload.cartId],
      cartCost: totalItemsCost(addItemToCart(state[action.payload.cartId].items, action.payload.itemId))(state),
      items: addItemToCart(state[action.payload.cartId].items, action.payload.itemId)
    }
  }
```

which uses:

```
export const addItemToCart = (items, newItem) => {
  const existingItem = items.find(item => item === newItem)

  if (existingItem) {
    return items
  } else {
    return [...items, newItem]
  }
}
```

But this gives me:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at item.selectors.js:18
    at index.js:70
    at index.js:30
    at index.js:84
    at index.js:30
    at cartReducer (cart.reducer.js:35)
    at combination (redux.js:459)
    at persistReducer.js:147
    at dispatch (redux.js:213)
    at redux-logger.js:1
    at index.js:11
    at dispatch (redux.js:638)
    at item.actions.js:30
```

All suggestions welcome, perhaps i'm not taking the correct approach creating the new field in the reducer? Thanks

Comment: `selectItems = itemIds => createSelector(` such usage of selectors does not make any sense nor effect, because you are re-creating the selector with every call and nothing gets memoized.

Comment: Redux aside, here's how I'd calculate the totals: https://jsfiddle.net/vo2egqhz/

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up with:

cart.selector.js:

```
export const selectAllCarts = state => state.carts

export const selectCart = cartId => createSelector(
  [selectAllCarts, selectAllItems],
  (carts, items) => generateCart(carts[cartId], items)
)

export const generateCart = (cart, allItems) => {
  return {
    ...cart,
    cartCost: calculateCartCost(allItems, cart.items)
  }
}
export const calculateCartCost = (allItems, cartItemIds) => {
  return Object.keys(allItems)
    .filter(itemId => cartItemIds.includes(itemId))
    .reduce((cost, itemId) => {
      cost += allItems[itemId].price
      return cost
    }, 0)
}

export const selectCarts = cartIds => createSelector(
  [selectAllCarts, selectAllItems],
  (carts, items) => Object.keys(carts)
    .filter(key => cartIds.includes(key))
    .reduce((arr, key) => {
      arr.push(generateCart(carts[key], items))
      return arr
    }, [])
)
```

That now gives me a list of carts that all have the cart cost field i can use to display. Pretty sure its not optimal but best i have :)